# Are mosquito nets and clothing necessary in Central and South America?

Tags: health, clothing, insects

I am considering going to Central and South America during April - June. I don't know how far into the jungles I will be going, but I certainly won't be going to the Amazon this time around. Is it necessary to have insect repellant clothing or mosquito net clothing for places such as Costa Rica, Machu Picchu, Patagonia, and Panama?

Answer (score 5):

According to [WHO reports](http://www.who.int/malaria/publications/country-profiles/en/index.html), there are a substantial number of Malaria cases in Peru and Panama, and [Costa Rica suffers from Dengue fever](http://www.therealcostarica.com/health_education_costa_rica/disease_costa_rica.html) so it would seem advisable to be careful there. I don't think there are diseases spread by mosquitoes in Patagonia, but they can be very annoying nonetheless.

Comment: Furthermore, the mosquitos there are very different. Even if you don't get an infectious disease, the bites can often swell and form whelps that can turn into open sores. It's not pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry for Patagonia: There are very few insects without any diseases. Peru in the high areas (Machu Picchu, Cuzco) is safe as well. For Central America, why not. Many carry one & don't use it. Some use it often... If you bring one, get a light one!

Comment: I just got this advice for Peru too: high areas not necessary, jungle area around Puerto Maldonado (east against Bolivia) use nets/clothing (pills not recommended). I will only be at PM for 4 days. Leishmaniasis considered more of a risk than dengue/malaria.